# Angular material stepper remove icons

Tags: angular-material

How to remove the icons in the mat-step-icon using angular material.

I tried below:

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit"></ng-template>
<ng-template matStepperIcon="done"></ng-template>
```

this works for edit and done state. want to change the default state as well. dont know what is the name to give.

can anyone help please?

thanks

Answer (score 22):

Here is a simple workaround from  the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10513)

```
@ViewChild(MatHorizontalStepper) stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stepper._getIndicatorType = () => 'number';
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The only thing that worked.

Answer (score 5):

On Angular Material v.14.1.3, you could add `completed="false"` properties in `<mat-step completed="false"></mat-step>`. the step icon will keep number index for selected step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following template to remove the icons from default state:

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="done"></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style in your css file of your angular project.

```
.yourParentDivCssClass ::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked for me after declaring mat-horizontal-stepper as parent! Tks.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api#StepState), the possible values for matStepperIcon are

```
number | edit | done | error
```

So for default state, you'll want to use `number` since you have `edit` and `done` covered.

You should end up with this:

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="number"></ng-template>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you want to remove all the icons on your material stepper one solution is to go to your `styles.css` file and add the following:

```
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This should do the trick